# inject bower dependencies with gulp - relative path issue

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I would like to inject bower dependencies with `gulp-inject` and `main-bower-files`. The dependencies are picked up but the paths generated are absolute.

I get `/www/lib/angular/angular.js` whereas I want `lib/angular/angular.js`

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="/www/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

**.bowerrc**

```
{
  "directory": "www/lib"
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');

gulp.task('index', function () {
    return gulp.src('./www/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {read: false}, {relative: true}), {name: 'bower'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'));
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrong use of options, the `relative` option should be in the `inject` and not in the `gulp.src`.

The correct task:

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
    return gulp.src('./www/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {read: false}), {name: 'bower', relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'));
});
```